# Django session variable not being saved when set using AJAX

Tags: angularjs, ajax, django, session

I am using database-backed sessions for my project. I am trying to update the value of a session variable via an AJAX post request using AngularJS:

```
app.factory('SomeFactory', ['$http', 'djangoUrl',
  function ($http, djangoUrl) {
    return {
      getSomeDataAndUpdateSessionVar: function () {
        return $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: djangoUrl.reverse('some_app:list'),
          data: {
            param1: "param1"
          }
        })
      },
    }
  }
]);
```

Here is the simplified post method of my View:

```
class DocumentListView(JsonRequestResponseMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request_data = json.loads(request.body)
        data_to_be_fetched = request.session.get("data_to_be_fetched", None)
        if not data_to_be_fetched:
            data_to_be_fetched = fetch_data(request_data)
            request.session["data_to_be_fetched"] = data_to_be_fetched
            print request.session.get("data_to_be_fetched")  # This will return the updated value

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data_to_be_fetched), content_type="application/json")
```

It seems like the session variable is not being saved because if I call the above method again, the value of `data_to_be_fetched` will still be `None`. The weird thing is that after calling the method for the second time, the new value of session variable will finally be saved (`data_to_be_fetched` will not be `None` anymore when fetched after saving it for the second time). Why is it behaving like that? It only happens when setting the session variable during AJAX requests.

I tried adding the following after updating the session variable, but the behavior is still the same:

```
request.session.modified = True
```

I also tried adding the following to the settings, but it is not helping either:

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is use localhost:8000 rather than 127.0.0.1:8000. Thefore always use 127.0.0.1:8000.
This fix to me.